# How query songs that have all the specified words from sql database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a database of songs and their words with the columns:
**serial , name , word.**

Primary key is serial.
The `Word` column contains only a single word.

I want to query songs that have all the words: "I love you" in their words.
**How can I do that in SQL?**

By the way I am using java to execute the statements so if that helps by any  built-in queries it can also be good.

An exmaple of the database rows:
`1  name1  love`
`1  name1  you`
`1  name1  why`
`1  name1  I`
`2  name2  love`
`2  name2  what`
`2  name2  we`

Comment: It can't be true that *"Primary key is serial"* because "serial" has the same value across multiple rows, and any primary key value can only appear in one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this structure, you will have to iteratively build a query with multiple subqueries, one for each word.  Assuming "serial" is a song identifier:

```
SELECT t1.serial, t1.name
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.word = 'I'
   AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.serial = t1.serial AND t2.word = 'love')
   AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.serial = t1.serial AND t2.word = 'you');
```

You'd continue adding `AND EXISTS...` for each word.  Ideally, you'd query for the most uncommon words first, to eliminate non-matching songs as early as possible.

An index on (word) will be valuable.  An index on (serial,word) may also be valuable.

The query optimizer should use a query like the one above to find all of the songs with the word 'I', and then for each of those songs, determine whether that song also has 'love' (or else it's excluded) then determine whether that song also has 'you' (or else it's excluded).

Note that your table is not in third normal form, since the only candidate key is (serial,word) and name is not functionally dependent on that, so your table structure has room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using WHERE EXISTS three times for the words I, love, and you.  You might need DISTINCT if the words are repeated several times.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Serial, Name
  FROM WordsTable WT1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM WordsTable WT2 WHERE WT1.Serial = WT2.Serial
                                              AND WT1.Name = WT2.Name
                                              AND WT2.Word = 'I')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM WordsTable WT2 WHERE WT1.Serial = WT2.Serial
                                              AND WT1.Name = WT2.Name
                                              AND WT2.Word = 'love')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM WordsTable WT2 WHERE WT1.Serial = WT2.Serial
                                              AND WT1.Name = WT2.Name
                                              AND WT2.Word = 'you');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name 
  from my_table 
 where word in ('i','love','you') 
 group 
    by name 
having count(distinct word) = 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * from [tablename]
WHERE word LIKE '%I love you%';
```

This query will get all tuples that have the exact string "I love you" somewhere in their `words` field.

For other Java specific stuff I recommend you look into prepared statements (help protect against SQL injections)

https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface

Comment: sorry doesn't work. Word column contains only 1 word